# ExtJS - How to style disabled buttons?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Even though it is possible to inspect styles of `enabled` buttons & customize them by creating CSS rules, tools such as **Chrome Dev Tools**, **Firebug**, **Firefox Dev Tools** are not able to inspect `disabled` buttons of ExtJS.

The question is that how can I customize them?

Here is a sample fiddle you can work on it: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/129h

Comment: `.x-btn.x-btn-disabled{your style goes here}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. Set your own [`disabledCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-disabledCls) ([example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/129j)).
2. Change the [CSS vars](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-css_var-S-button-default-background-color-disabled) of [`button`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.button.Button).